# Java - Array List Cumulation

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am working on a project where I have a user enter two values

1) Country of Birth (ISO Short Code, such as US, UK, IN, etc)

2) Current Age.

At the end of the program, I'd like to output a breakdown of age by country, such as :

US: 1 - 10 (5 people) 11 - 20 (10 people)

UK: 1 - 10 (2 people) 11 - 20 ( 15 people) etc

I'm not even sure where to start with this.

Right now I have user entries (via Scanner) for both age and country of birth going to individual ArrayLists -- but I have no idea how to get the cumulative output.

Any suggestions or ideas on where I can look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you not put the countries and ages into separate lists. Instead create a single class to store both. It will look something like:

```
class Person {
    private final String country;
    private final int age;
}
```

Then have a list of `Person` objects that are created as the user enters data:

```
List<Person> people;
```

Classifying into country and age groups can be done in lots of different ways. The simplest is to build a multi level map that stores the information:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> classification;
```

In this case the first string is the country, the second string is the age bucket and the third is the count. The count of UK people aged 11-20 would be `classification.get("UK").get("11-20")`.

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, is there a good way to do this without lists? I haven't gotten that far in my tutorials and the programming challenge is assuming we can do this with Arrays

Comment: Yes you can do it with arrays. I note however that you have 'arraylist' as a tag of your question which is an implementation of `List`.

Comment: Sprinter -- can you advise on how to best create an unlimited list of person objects that would be created?

Comment: @user5568948 I'm not sure what you're asking. All Java collections are effectively unlimited (ignoring memory constraints). You just create the list, create each person object and add to the list. If you're not sure how to do that, start with the standard Java tutorial then ask another question if you get stuck.